# Qt and opencv in a Visual Studio 2013 Console Application

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use Qt and OpenCV in Visual Studio 2013. OpenCV is working fine; however, when I try to link to Qt libraries, I get the error:

OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The library is compiled without QT support) in cv::fontQt, file ....

I have installed the Visual Studio Add-in. What else do I need to do to get this working. I've looked on the Internet for how to do this, but most pages I find seem to require using QtCreator, or making a QtProject inside Visual Studio. I need to have a console application in Visual Studio that links to Qt. I am a complete beginner with Qt, and a beginner with C++ and Opencv.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the library folder into the Project Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories location.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I already have that, but I'm still getting the same error during runtime.